# Grafeas golang filter string and DeleteOccurrence() API errors

Tags: go, grafeas

I'm running into 2 separate issues using the Grafeas golang v1beta1 API.

**What I'm trying to do**

- Call ListOccurrencesRequest() with a Filter to get a list of occurrences for deletion
- Call DeleteOccurrence() on each occurrence from above list to delete it

**Issue #1**

I'm trying to set the Filter field using this [GCP reference](https://cloud.google.com/container-analysis/docs/get-image-vulnerabilities#viewing_discovery_occurrences) grafeas golang code as a guide.

```
filterStr := fmt.Sprintf(`kind=%q`, grafeas_common_proto.NoteKind_BUILD.String())
listReq := &grafeas_proto.ListOccurrencesRequest{
    Parent:   BuildProject,
    Filter:   filterStr,
    PageSize: 100,
}

listOccResp, err := r.grafeasCommon.ListOccurrences(ctx, listReq)
for {
        if err != nil {
            log.Error("failed to iterate over occurrences", zap.NamedError("error", err))
            return nil, err
        }
        ...
```

But it looks like my filterStr is invalid, here's the error:

```
filterStr       {"filterStr": "kind=\"BUILD\""}
failed to iterate over occurrences      {"error": "rpc error: code = Internal desc = error while parsing filter expression: 4 errors occurred:\n\t* error parsing filter\n\t* Syntax error: token recognition error at: '=\"' (1:4)\n\t* Syntax error: token recognition error at: '\"' (1:11)\n\t* Syntax error: extraneous input 'BUILD' expecting <EOF> (1:6)\n\n"}
```

It looks like the `\` escape character is causing trouble but I've tried it without it and get another flavor of same type of error.

**Issue #2**

When I call `DeleteOccurrence()`, I can see that the occurrence is in fact deleted from Grafeas by checking:

`curl http://localhost:8080/v1beta1/projects/broker_builds/occurrences`

But `DeleteOccurrence()` always sets the `err`

Code:

```
    for _, o := range occToDelete {
        log.Info("occToDelete", zap.String("occurrence", o))
        _, err := r.grafeasCommon.DeleteOccurrence(ctx, &grafeas_proto.DeleteOccurrenceRequest{
            Name: o,
        })
        if err != nil {
            log.Error("failed to delete occurrence", zap.String("occurrence", o), zap.NamedError("error", err))
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
failed to delete occurrence     {"occurrence": "projects/broker_builds/occurrences/f61a4c57-a3d3-44a9-86ee-5d58cb6c6052", "error": "rpc error: code = Internal desc = grpc: error while marshaling: proto: Marshal called with nil"}
```

I don't understand what the error is referring to.

This question was cross-posted on [Grafeas message board](https://groups.google.com/g/grafeas-users/c/2sldhhYY1Vo).

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution for Issue #1**

I'm using grafeas-elasticsearch as the storage backend. It uses a different filter string format than the examples I had looked at in my original post.

For example, instead of `=` -> `==`, `AND` -> `&&`, etc.

More examples can be seen here:
https://github.com/rode/grafeas-elasticsearch/blob/main/test/v1beta1/occurrence_test.go#L226

**Solution for Issue #2**

Known issue with grafeas

https://github.com/grafeas/grafeas/pull/456

https://github.com/grafeas/grafeas/pull/468

Unfortunately the latest tagged release of grafeas v0.1.6 does not include these fixes yet. So will need to pick them up on the next release.

Thanks to @Ovidiu Ghinet, that was a good tip

Comment: yes, I hope we get a new release soon also.

otherwise I have been cherrypick for the last 6 months or so...

go get github.com/grafeas/grafeas@master 
or 
go get github.com/grafeas/grafeas@5b072a9930ea or some other commit known to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Can you shed some details around the storage engine used, and the filtering implementations details?

Issue 1. filtering is not implemented in any of the storage engines in gitHub.com/grafeas/grafeas.

Issue 2. it depends what store you use, memstore/embededstore do not seem to be producing any errors similar to what you mentioned... if using postgresql store, are you trying to delete an occurrence twice?

Comment: You were spot on for issue #1, it was because I was using grafeas-elasticsearch, which has a different filtering string format. I will post an answer to explain